Can I take a walking stick on an Alaska Airlines flight?
I have a thick wooden stick, decorated and has tape. And it is NOT a weapon; it doesn’t fit in my bag. but can I still keep it? I’m traveling to Oregon, and the flight I’m going on is Alaska Airlines.

This is not use for any sports, it helps me stand up and it has support tape, etc.

So, it's a walking stick?

It may, sadly, depend on how they perceive your mobility. At their option they may gate check it to be returned on the jet bridge at the next stop.


Can I take a walking stick on an Alaska Airlines flight?

Canes are allowed as carry-on according to https://www.alaskaair.com/content/about-us/customer-commitment/customer-commitment-special-needs

Compact mobility devices (such as manual wheelchairs, canes, and walkers) can be taken onboard the aircraft into the passenger cabin. If an item cannot be safely stowed in the cabin, it will be specially tagged, placed in the cargo compartment, and returned promptly at the next stop. Electric wheelchairs must be safely secured in the cargo compartment during flight.

Hiking/trekking poles are not allowed as carry-on according  to https://news.alaskaair.com/guest-experience/sports-equipment-update/:

Hiking/trekking poles are only allowed in checked baggage, per TSA policy.


That leaves the question, do the airlines or the security staff see it as a cane or as a pole? If it is solid wood, quite heavy I doubt they let it in the cabin.

Hiking/trekking poles do tend to have sharp pointy ends in them, so that may be the distinction.
